# Add White Gaussian Noise MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, noise

When we use following Matlab function

```
signal=awgn(signal,5,'measured')
```

How much SNR do we have added to original signal?
I mean the SNR is 5 dB?
How can I add 20 dB noise to signal by using this command?

Comment: According to the docs, the SNR of your syntax will be 5dB. So just change your `5` to a `20` if you want 20dB...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Dan has mentioned in the comments, the second argument is used to set the value of SNR.

However, this is under the assumption that your `signal` has a power of 0 dBW. In case the signal power is different, you need to increase (or decrease) the value of the `snr` argument appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. How can I add 5 dB noise to one signal how I did not its power ? Is any formula for that ?

Comment: SNR stands for signal-to-noise ratio. 5 dB SNR means that the value of the noise power is 5 dB less than the signal power. So, you definitely need to know the signal power. See here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/examples/measuring-the-power-of-deterministic-periodic-signals.html on how to calculate the signal power. Then determine the power of the noise signal to be added.